# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred for 'Optional<Array<_>>'

Tags: swift, generics, core-data

I'm getting this error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Optional<Array<_>>' to specified type
> '[FoodEntity]'. Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

```
 func fetch<T:NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:String) throws -> [T] {
      
        let request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: entityName)
        
        let entities = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        
        return entities
        
    }
```

but I have the type in the call `[FoodEntity]`

```
    let foodArray:[FoodEntity] = try PersistenceController.shared.fetch(entityName: "FoodEntity")
```

Comment: You have a mismatch in optionality between your left and right hand sides. Try `let foodArray:[FoodEntity]? = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generic type should extend `NSManagedObject`

```
func fetch<T:NSManagedObject>(entityName:String) ...
```

Comment: I crashes on line `let entities = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)`

Comment: Error message, what kind of crash?

Comment: Gonna mark this as the correct answer because the reason of the crash was elsewhere